# Keras Tuner returning an empty list when calling get_best_hyperparameters() and get_best_models(num_models=1)?

Tags: python, keras, keras-tuner

I am trying to use Keras Tuner to tune hyperparameters but I am running into trouble. After I run tuner.search() with well-formed inputs and the search successfully runs, `tuner.get_best_hyperparameters()` and `tuner.get_best_models(num_models=1)` both return empty lists. I am not sure what is the source of this error. The search is definitely running correctly as I am seeing accuracies for each batch in the search. Let me know how to proceed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is likely originated in **not** calling of `tuner.search` before calling the `get_best_*` (hyperparameters or models).